# Solving $\partial_t \gamma_t(x) = - \gamma_t(x) + \frac{\gamma_t''(x)}{\gamma_t'(x)^2}$, a nonlinear PDE on quantile functions

Tags: partial-differential-equations, information-theory, nonlinear-system, gradient-flows, quantile-function

While pondering Wasserstein-2 gradient flows of the [Kullback-Leibler divergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kullback%E2%80%93Leibler_divergence#Definition) functional $\text{KL}(\cdot \mid \nu)$, where $\nu \sim \mathcal N(0, 1)$ is the standard normal distribution (yes, I know about Langevin dynamics and Fokker-Planck, but I am coming to this from a different angle), I arrived at the following second order nonlinear PDE on quantile functions:
\begin{equation} \label{eq:1} \tag{$\star$}
\partial_t \gamma_t(x) = - \gamma_t(x) + \frac{\gamma_t''(x)}{\gamma_t'(x)^2}, \qquad \forall x \in (0, 1), \ \forall t > 0
\end{equation}
with some initial condition $\gamma_0(x) = f(x)$, where $f$ is a quantile function of a probability measure on $\mathbb R$, e.g. $f(x) = \ln\left(\frac{x}{1-x}\right)$, which is the quantile function of a [logistic distribution](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_distribution).

> I am trying to solve this equation or at least "get a feel" for it.

### Edit

Through the connection with W2-gradient flows of the KL-divergence I am relatively sure that the densities $p_t := (\gamma_t^{-1})'$ must fulfill the Fokker-Planck equation $\partial_t p_t(x) = \Delta p_t(x) + x \cdot \nabla p_t(x) + p_t(x)$, but I don't know how to prove this connection.

In particular, if I did everything right in deriving this equation (which I am not sure about at all), then $\gamma_t$ should tend, for $t \to \infty$, to the quantile function of the standard normal distribution $\mathcal N(0, 1)$ and if the initial condition is the quantile function of a normal distribution, $\gamma_t$ should remain the quantile function of some normal distribution for all $t \ge 0$.

The following is a plot the evolution for the above mentioned initial condition, but the simulation breaks down for $t > \frac{1}{2}$. [image: 1D KL W2 GF]

### Ideas

- The steady-state solution of \eqref{eq:1}, that is, the solution to $- \gamma(x) + \frac{\gamma''(x)}{\gamma'(x)^2}$ is $\gamma(x) = \sqrt{2} \text{erf}^{-1}\left( \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}} c_1 (x + c_2) \right)$.
- I tried taking the Fourier transform (with respect to $x$) of \eqref{eq:1}, but I couldn't handle the term $\frac{\gamma_t''(x)}{\gamma_t'(x)^2} = - \frac{d}{d x} \frac{1}{\gamma_t'(x)}$.
- Looking for invariants of \eqref{eq:1}, I noticed that if $\gamma$ solves the equation, then neither $\gamma + a$, $a \cdot \gamma$, $\frac{1}{\gamma}$ nor $(t, x) \mapsto \gamma_t(1 - x)$ solve \eqref{eq:1}, where $a \in \mathbb R$ is a constant.
- The separable ansatz $\gamma_t(x) = T(t) X(x)$ leads to $T'(t) T(t) + T(t)^2 = \frac{X''(x)}{X'(x)^2 X(x)}$ if $X(x) \ne 0$, so that we have $T'(t) T(t) + T(t)^2 = \lambda$ and $X''(x) = \lambda X'(x)^2 X(x)$ for some constant $\lambda \in \mathbb R$.
  Hence $T(t) = \pm \sqrt{e^{C_1 - 2 t} + \lambda}$ and $X(x) = \sqrt{\frac{2}{\lambda}} \text{erf}^{-1}\left(\sqrt{\lambda} \tilde{c_1} (x + c_2) \right)$.
- The separable ansatz $\gamma_t(x) = T(t) + X(x)$ yields
  $T'(t) = - T(t) - X(x) + \frac{X''(x)}{X'(x)^2}$ and thus $T'(t) + T(t) = \lambda$ and $\frac{X''(x)}{X'(x)^2} = \lambda + X(x)$ and thus $T(t) = c_1 e^{-t} + \lambda$ and $X(x) = \sqrt{2} \text{erf}^{-1}\left(\tilde{c_1} e^{-\frac{1}{2} \lambda^2} (c_2 + x)\right) - \lambda$, which leads to the IMO "nicer"
  $$
  \gamma_t(x)
  = c_1 e^{-t} + \sqrt{2} \text{erf}^{-1}\left(\tilde{c_1} e^{-\frac{1}{2} \lambda^2} (c_2 + x)\right).
  $$

These two ansatz generate families of solutions. Are those all the solutions?

Comment: Wolfram gives a solution to the steady-state equation in terms of $\mathrm{erf}^{-1}(ax+b)$ as well. The functional $F[\gamma_t] = \int_0^1 \gamma_{t}(x)^2(x) \ dx$ follows the equation $F' = -F + 1 - \left[\frac{\gamma_t}{\gamma'_t}\right]_{0}^1$. I believe for both your ansatz the boundary term tends to a constant so the equation tends to constant $L^2$ norm like $e^{-t}$. This seems to indicate that this $\mathrm{erf}^{-1}$ function might be a stable fixed point for some class of initial conditions with nice boundary behavior.

Comment: @whpowell96 Thanks very much for your answer, I will look into it. Also see the edit.

Comment: Ignore the extra $x$ in the integrand

Answer (score 2):

Since it seems that $\gamma_t'$ is sometimes (always?) positive, it may be possible to invert, and let me denote $\gamma_t$ as $u(x,t)$, as
$$          x = r(u,t).
$$
If so, the equation $u_t+u=\frac{u_{xx}}{u_x^2}$ (subscripts
now denoting derivatives)
linearizes as
$$
    r_t = u r_u+r_{uu}.
$$
That has a lot of solutions, but I have not tried to see how they might relate to the separable ones that you have given.

Comment: Since this $\gamma_t$ should be a quantile function and thus nonincreasing, $\gamma_t'$ should be nonnegative for every $t \ge 0$.